# Python: Basic Namedtuple Collections for VB Programmers

Tags: python, namedtuple

I'm developing my first "Hello World" on Python! I used to be Visual Basic programmer a long long time ago...

I'm trying to use Namedtuple Collections like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
import collections
    
#Tipo da colecao
File = collections.namedtuple('File',['abspath' ,'basename','filextention','filetype'])
Files = []
    
Files.append(File('/home/user/teste1.txt', 'teste1.txt','txt',''))
Files.append(File('/home/user/teste2.txt', 'teste2.txt','txt',''))
Files.append(File('/home/user/teste3.txt', 'teste2.txt','txt',''))
    
for lCtd in range(0,len(Files)):
    print(Files[lCtd].abspath,Files[lCtd].basename,Files[lCtd].filextention)
    
for lCtd in range(0,len(Files)):
    #>>>>>How can I do this?!<<<<< 
    Files[lCtd].filetype = 'A'
```

If have a best way to do this(or the all code), I'm all ears...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `namedtuple`s are immutable. You could try using a list of `dict`s instead, or [recordtype](https://pypi.org/project/recordtype/).

Comment: Great! How can this works? Could you show with the code (using the same logic that I'm trying above)? I started in Python this weekend... sorry

Comment: Maybe it's different in VB, but in Python, it's much discouraged to have variable names start with uppercase characters (`file`, not `File`, `files`, not `Files`). Uppercase first characters signal a type vs a variable.

Comment: Thanks @Steve! I have a lot of thing to learn in Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you really want here is to define your own class, like this:

```
class File:
    # make a constructor, with a default parameter (for convenience!)
    def __init__(self, abspath, basename, filextention, filetype = ''):
        self.abspath = abspath
        self.basename = basename
        self.filextention = filextention
        self.filetype = filetype

Files = []

# this part is almost the same, but you don't need the last parameter
# because we gave it a default value    
Files.append(File('/home/user/teste1.txt', 'teste1.txt','txt'))
Files.append(File('/home/user/teste2.txt', 'teste2.txt','txt'))
Files.append(File('/home/user/teste3.txt', 'teste2.txt','txt'))

# this is a better way to loop over a list in Python:
for curFile in Files:
    print(curFile.abspath, curFile.basename, curFile.filextention)

for curFile in Files:
    curFile.filextention = 'A' # in Python all fields are public by default and can be assigned like this
```

Comment: Is possible that one "field"of my class File can be on other Class?

abspath 
basename
filextention
filetype
image ( DataCreated, Size )

Comment: for curFile in Files:
    curFile.filextention = 'A' 

When I do this I change the values in the "Files class"?

Comment: @Fperuso 1. I don't understand your first question. 2. `Files` is a Pyhton list. It does not have a `filextention` field and can not have one. But, the last two lines of the code are a loop, that goes over all `File` objects in that list and changes the `filextention` of every object individually. If you want to change just one of them, do something like this without `for`: `Files[0].filextention = 'B'

Answer (score 1):

Named tuples are useful, but they are *immutable*: their attributes cannot be changed after they're created. If you want a similarly convenient data-holder that's mutable, you might be interested in [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), as long as you're using Python 3.7 or newer.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class File:
    file_name: str
    abs_path: str
    base_name: str
    file_extension: str
    # The '=' below sets a default value. (You could use '', but None is more
    # commonly used for this.)
    file_type: str =  None

files = [
    File('/home/user/test1.txt', 'test1.txt', 'txt'),
    File('/home/user/test2.txt', 'test2.txt', 'txt'),
    File('/home/user/test3.txt', 'test3.txt', 'txt'),
]
    
for file in files:
    print(file.abs_path, file.base_name, file.file_extension)
    # This will update the file_type attribute for each file:
    file.file_type = 'A'
```

Note that the more Pythonic way to loop through a list (or any sequence) is to not rely on `len` and an index, but simply to loop through the items themselves.

All this said, if you're looking for a simple way to work with files, such as getting their names and extensions, you should probably also look at [Pathlib](https://jefftriplett.com/2017/pathlib-is-wonderful/).

```py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('/home/user/test1.txt')
print(str(file), file.name, file.suffix)

# Output: /home/user/test1.txt test1.txt .txt
```

P.S. `file` was a builtin in Python 2, and many editors may still highlight it as such, but it should be fine to use as a variable/class name in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for my basic questions... I faced one problem:     

"from dataclasses import dataclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'"

I have CentOS 7...

And I have a question in the code: I would like to update the "column" file_type in the "files" 

And I have a question: I would like to update the "column" file_type in the "files"

Comment: @Fperuso You must have an older version of Python. You need version 3.7 or newer. Typing `python --version` on the command line should tell you what you have. And you update an attribute ("column") by simply assigning to it. See the line `file.file_type = 'A'`.

Comment: You are correct! I'm using 2.7.5. I don't know if I update it, will mess my OS

Comment: Python 2 is no longer supported. You should really try and install Python 3, if possible. (For how to do that, look around here on SO or Google, but it's probably pretty simple with your OS's package manager.)

Comment: @Fperuso actually, Python 2 and Python 3 are considered separate programs because there is no backwards compatibility. I am not sure about CentOS, but many Linux distributions have both Python 2 and 3 installed side by side. Try typing `python3 -v ` to check if Python 3 is installed and what version. Note that you may have some system apps depending on a specific Python version. You should check Google and CentOS forums before upgrading. Also, CentOS is a sever distro, and not recommended for desktop use. If you can choose, try latest Ubuntu.